# zsh in IntelliJ

Tags: bash, shell, intellij-idea, zsh

I wanted to get a zsh terminal running in IntelliJ, I set up an external tool which was just zsh and set the working directory to my home directory.  When I ran it however there were 2 problems straight away:

1. My .zprofile hadn't been loaded
2. Tab didn't auto-complete anything

Does anyone know if I can get zsh working nicely inside IntelliJ?

Comment: There is no easy way to do it as IDEA doesn't have a real terminal yet, see the related issue: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-5166.

Comment: This feature will be available in IntelliJ IDEA 13! Fish in IntelliJ - awesomeness !

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Confirmed! Available in IntelliJ 13

[image: zsh terminal]

Answer (score 0):

For me it still was using Bourne shell even though I selected /bin/zsh in the prefernces window.
What helped was to execute

```bash
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

After restarting intelij terminal, zsh was properly started